# Tools for auditing software license compliance

Tags: licensing

We need to get Office install numbers and compare them to license counts in order to ensure compliance. What tools are there for querying software installations on the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- We have used [OCS Inventory](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/) in the past with good success.
- Additionally, [Tracmor](http://www.tracmor.com/) looks interesting as well, but perhaps for a slightly different need.
- Lastly, [Fusion Inventory](http://fusioninventory.org/wordpress/) looks like it might be helpful as well.
- The one thing that we did not care for with [SpiceWorks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) was the inclusion of all of the adds that appeared within the product and the large amounts e-mail that one receives from the company.

Answer (score 2):

[Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) will do this, and it's free and awesome.

Comment: Thanks for this link.  I'd seen this during my many, many research travails and I meant to go back to it.  Your post has re-piqued my interest...

Answer (score 1):

Please check lansweeper. You can get it download from http://www.lansweeper.com/. This is great tool and let you know about all product installed in PC as well as network.

Answer (score 0):

Network Asset Manager is lightweight and free:

http://www.5dollartools.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4:network-asset-manager&catid=3:products&Itemid=5

It does not do automated scans (yet), but works well for cases where you have machines with non-domain joined (i.e. different credentials) to get admin.